# How to make a model equation in R fixest and choose factor interactions

Tags: r, estimation

I have a difference-in-difference model which I want to estimate with fixed effects on R. I want to include exposure and treatment interactions to calculate leading and lagging effects.

Basically, I have variables that are collinear and want to choose which one to exclude from my model. A few days ago this would have been really simple with the `lfe` package one could just do:

```
library(data.table)
library(fixest)

crime <- fread("crime.csv")

# Time as a factor for fixed effects
crime[, time := factor(time)]

# Model
xx <- model.matrix(any_crime ~ treatment:time - 1, data = crime) # time is a factor

# Set period 12 as base
xx[, "treatment:time12"] <- 0

# Model with leads and lags
m1 <- felm(any_crime ~ xx | id + time, data = crime)
```

However, now that `lfe` is archived I have turned to the `fixest` package which is much faster. However I can't get `feols()` to accept my `model.matrix`. As doing the same thing as above but replaceing `felm()` with `feols()` gives the following error:

```
> feols(any_crime ~ xx | id + time, data = crime)
Error in feols(any_crime ~ xx | id + time, data = crime)
  The variable xx is in the RHS of the formula but not in the dataset.
```

I have read `?feols()` and the formula argument says nothing about model matrices and the details section is one sentence long.

`fixest` also has `model.matrix.fixest`, I have also checked help for this function and it says it takes a `fixest` object as its first argument. I have been unable to use this to create a model that sets period 12 as the base period.

---

[Here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f144e21f62266b586595126c2a90088120201210003427/1cfa1e) is a small sample of data for reproducibility.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All variables in the formula of `fixest` estimations must be in the data set: contrary to `lm` or `felm`, there is no evaluation from the global environment.

But your case can be easily dealt with with the function `i()`. Here's an example from the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fixest/vignettes/fixest_walkthrough.html):

```
library(fixest)
data(base_did)
est_did = feols(y ~ x1 + i(treat, period, 5) | id + period, base_did)
est_did
#> OLS estimation, Dep. Var.: y
#> Observations: 1,080 
#> Fixed-effects: id: 108,  period: 10
#> Standard-errors: Clustered (id) 
#>                   Estimate Std. Error   t value  Pr(>|t|)    
#> x1                0.973490   0.045678 21.312000 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> treat:period::1  -1.403000   1.110300 -1.263700  0.209084    
#> treat:period::2  -1.247500   1.093100 -1.141200  0.256329    
#> treat:period::3  -0.273206   1.106900 -0.246813  0.805526    
#> treat:period::4  -1.795700   1.088000 -1.650500  0.101769    
#> treat:period::6   0.784452   1.028400  0.762798  0.447262    
#> treat:period::7   3.598900   1.101600  3.267100  0.001461 ** 
#> treat:period::8   3.811800   1.247500  3.055500  0.002837 ** 
#> treat:period::9   4.731400   1.097100  4.312600   3.6e-05 ***
#> treat:period::10  6.606200   1.120500  5.895800   4.4e-08 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> Log-likelihood: -2,984.58   Adj. R2: 0.48783 
#>                           R2-Within: 0.38963
```

The function `i()` performs an interaction between a continuous variable (although it can be a factor too) and a factor (the 2nd element is always treated as a factor). You can then add the arguments `ref` and/or `drop` and/or `keep` to specify which level from the factor to keep. (The difference between `ref` and `drop` is subtle: `ref` accepts only one value [`drop` accepts many] and that reference is highlighted when using `coefplot` on the estimation.)

In the previous example, we have `ref = 5`, so the 5th period will be excluded from the interaction.

Back to your example, the following should work (without creating any extra data):

```
feols(any_crime ~ i(treatment, time, 12) | id + time, data = crime)
```

It's then easy to rebase or drop several:

```
feols(any_crime ~ i(treatment, time, 10) | id + time, data = crime)
feols(any_crime ~ i(treatment, time, drop = 10:12) | id + time, data = crime)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! this works perfectly and it is hard to over state how useful this is. Thanks!!